# BigQuery cross join to check distance between record in 3m records table?

Tags: google-bigquery, cross-join

I have a table with around 3 million records which contains lat and long. I would like to compare the distance between each record to check which record probably be the same place or nearby place.

For the small testing table I use cross join and the distance function but for this 3m table, cross join is the problem.

Do you have any suggestion or solution?

Comment: Note that BigQuery optimizes geospatial join, and cross join of 3m table by 3m table should be fine. See this tip about checking you get optimized join: https://mentin.medium.com/execution-details-for-spatial-join-7274356e0115

Answer (score 0):

> but for this 3m table, cross join is the problem.
> ... any suggestion ... ?

You can use [ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_clusterdbscan) to partition your records into clusters and than cross join not all 3M records with each other but rather only those within the same partition / cluster

Below example of how cluster the geo points

```
ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude), 5000, 1) over() cluster
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that.